# How to redirect to new component with props on submit using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes, arguments

I'm new to React and Javascript. I have this handleSubmit function that successfully returns the correct values for organizationId and severity upon submit of a Formik form. How can I route, or redirect to the path specified below, with the props/arguments passed to the FilteredReports componenent? In short, I'm filtering a list of items based on these properties.

```
export class Report extends Component<IProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
        <Formik
              component={Form}
              initialValues={{ organizationId: '', severity: '' }}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
    )
  }

private handleSubmit = async (
    values: { organizationId: any, severity: any },
    { setSubmitting }: FormikActions<{ organizationId: any, severity: any}>,
  ) => {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props

    if (onSubmit !== undefined) {
      try {
        setSubmitting(true)
        await onSubmit(values.organizationId, values.severity) 
        return <Redirect to={FILTERED_REPORT} component={FilteredReport({id: values.organizationId, severity: values.severity})} />
      } finally {
        setSubmitting(false)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The FilteredReports component looks like this:

```
export const FilteredReport = ({ id, severity }: { id: string, severity: number }) =>
  loadComponentData(GET_FILTERED_REPORT_ASSETS_AND_EVENTS, { id, severity }, (data) => (
    <ReportScreen items={buildFilteredReportItems(data.reportOrganizations, data.facilities, data.lines, data.assets, data.events)} />
  ))
```

The values are defined, but onSubmit is undefined for some reason. Also receiving a typeError that onSubmit is not a function. I've tried placing the redirect outside of the try, but I get an invalid hook call. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: my form is defined as so:

```
export const Form = ({
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  isSubmitting,
  values,
}: FormikProps<{ organizationId: any, severity: any }>) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    <Box pt={4}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="organization-native-required">Organization</InputLabel>
      <Select
          native
          value={values.organizationId}
          onChange={handleChange('organizationId')}
          name="organizationId"
          inputProps={{
            id: 'organization-native-required',
          }}
        >
          <option value='-1'></option>
          {getOrganizations()}
        </Select>
    </Box>

    <Box pt={4}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="severity-native-required">Severity</InputLabel>
      <Select
          native
          value={values.severity}
          onChange={handleChange('severity')}
          name="severity"
          inputProps={{
            id: 'severity-native-required',
          }}
        >
          <option value='-1'></option>
          <option value='0'>Suspect</option>
          <option value='1'>Warning</option>
          <option value='2'>Critical</option>
        </Select>
    </Box>

    <Box pt={4}>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        data-testid="submit-button"
        disabled={isSubmitting}
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
      >
        Filter
      </Button>
    </Box>

  </form>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "args" you are talking about are props. In React, props are passed from a parent component to a child component. So, you would pass them through from whatever component renders your FilteredReport component, like this:

```js
<Parent> 
<FilteredComponent id={whatever} severity={whatver}/>
</Parent>
```

If you want the component to have default props, you can do check out this link [conditionally set default props](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/conditionally-set-default-props/), but note that you wouldnt normally do this in react. Instead you should consider using [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).